# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState. Как решить?

Tags: android

Слишком много кода, чтобы его здесь весь выкладывать, поэтому постараюсь объяснить вкратце:

В главной активити я отображаю фрагмент карты с маркерами, и по нажатию маркера в углу экрана отображается фрагмент фото с тремя кнопками. Взаимодействие активити и фрагмента через колбэк. Проблема в том, что при повороте экрана, если фрагмент был уже запущен и отображается, после нажатия на его кнопки не удается обновить пользовательский интерфейс активити. А при попытке удалить фрагмент из FragmentManager (запуская из класса активити), выдает IllegalStateException!

```
Вкратце:

public interface RouteComposeListener extends Serializable{
...
    void onRemoveFragment(int tag);
}

public class TinyPictureFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private RouteComposeListener listener;
    private int tag;
    private static final String EXTRA_LISTENER_ARG = "listener";
    private static final String EXTRA_TAG_ARG = "tag";
     ...
    private ImageView mExcludePoint;

    public static TinyPictureFragment newInstance(RouteComposeListener listener, int tag) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(EXTRA_TAG_ARG, tag);
        bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_LISTENER_ARG, listener);
        TinyPictureFragment fragment = new TinyPictureFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            listener = (RouteComposeListener) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_LISTENER_ARG);
            tag = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_TAG_ARG);
             ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mini_image, container, false);

        mExcludePoint = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove_point_id);

        mExcludePoint.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            ...
            case R.id.btn_remove_point_id:
                listener.onRemoveFragment(tag);
                break;
           ...
            default:
                Log.i(TAG, "default");
                break;
        }
    }
}

Далее методы из активити:

//Из этого метода я создаю фрагмент в активности
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        int tag;
        if (marker != null) {

            tag = (int) marker.getTag();

            TinyPictureFragment fragment = TinyPictureFragment.newInstance(this, tag);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_id, fragment, "fragment")
                    .commit();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveFragment(int tag) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment"))
                .commit(); // здесь вылетает java.lang.IllegalStateException
    }
```

Comment: Сериализация листнера -- весьма странная затея.

Comment: Не заметил, надо удалить (просто была попытка сохранить listener в Fragment.onSaveInstanceState() - результат тот же).

Comment: post_zeew ,благодарю. Убрал сериализацию и все заработало!